# How can I pass a variable from one generator to another in Python?

Tags: python

I have the following 2 generators:

```
a = 20

def function1():
    coin = np.random.randint(0, 100)
    a2= a+coin
    yield a2


def function2():
    yield a2
```

I want to pass `a2` to `function2`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: These functions don't make sense. Why are they generators at all, if they only yield a single value? Why not write regular functions?

Comment: Typically generators are used to "generate" multiple values, i.e. contain some kind of loop. Having only one `yield` doesn't take any advantage of generators.

Comment: What problem would you like to solve here?

Comment: Mike, [here](https://gist.github.com/dimjones82/5bfa298572ea727fda6282d3291755c6) is my problem. Look at line 26. In this case, the image and mask generator are what I am trying to create (i,e., the `function1` and `function2`). The issue is that my function1 (i.e., image generator) calls a random sampling selection, where the value of this random selection must also be applied to function2 (i,e., the 2nd generator 'mask'). Note I am creating my own image and mask generators and not using the one defined in the gist code.

Comment: It is still not clear how the generators are used in the end. Please try to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completly sure if this is what you are looking for, but  generators have a method called 'send' which enables you to pass data to the generator.
You might want to read this [example](https://franklingu.github.io/programming/2016/02/11/understanding-python-generator/). Pay attention to the functions 'consume' and 'produce'.