# How to add option with Click CLI and pass the option correctly into functions?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, click, command-line-interface, boto3

I'm taking my first programming course so please pardon if questions are too naive.
I'm using Python Boto3 module and 'Click' library to build a Command Line Interface that manages EC2 instances.
Code:

```
@click.group()
@cli.group('instances')
def instances():
    pass
@instances.command('list')
@click.option('--project', default=None,help='List instances by project tag, e.g. -project = <project name>')
def list_instances(project):
    'List EC2 instances'
    instances = filter_project_instances(project)
    for i in instances:
            print(', '.join((
            i.id,
            i.instance_type,
        )))
        return

@cli.group('volumes')
#Details of this 'volumes' command are omitted for simplification
```

Basically, 'Click' allows me to wrap my functions with commands (e.g. instances, volumes), subcommands(list) and option (--project).
Such a command line:
****shotty.py instances list --project Valkyrie****
can list instances that are tagged with the name 'Valkyrie'

Now, I'm required to add an option to this command line to specify the AWS profile I wanna use to log in. The profile was created with 'aws configure --profile [profile name]' command (profile names can be Dan, Kyle, etc.):

****shotty.py --profile [profile name] instances list****

Initially, I hardcoded the profile name and used **session** and **ec2** as global variables that any other functions can use.

```
import boto3
import botocore
import click

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='Dan')
ec2 = session.resource('ec2')
```

Though implementing the above requirement, based on 'Click' documents, I had to do the following to add such a '--profile' option:

```
@click.group()
@click.option('--profile', default=None,help='Select the AWS profile')
def cli(profile):
   session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profile)
   ec2 = session.resource('ec2')
```

But now, **session** and **ec2** are not available to other functions any more.
This cli() function is like an entry point of the script and is revoked in the main() function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

My only approach I could think of was creating a separate function

```
  def session(profile):
        session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profile)
        ec2 = session.resource('ec2')
        return ec2
```

But now this brings another issue that I have to add **profile** as a parameter to all other functions, e.g.

```
def filter_project_instances(project, profile):
        'Filter EC2 instances'
        ec2 = session(profile)
        instances = ec2.instances.all()
        return instances
```

This means I have to define **profile** again somehow in this **filter_project_instances** function. It does not make much sense to me. Any help would be appreciated!
Update: I had a look at the global keyword before posting but most searches told me that having global variable was mostly a sign of a bad design so I was thinking that I was lacking something pythonically to make it work here

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting, seemed like the most suitable solution is make my **profile** variable global by

```
@click.group()
@click.option('--profile', default = None, help='Select the AWS profile')
def cli(profile):
    "Shotty manages snapshots"
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profile)
    ec2_cli = session.resource('ec2')
    global ec2
    ec2 = ec2_cli
```

Though this approach is usually frowned upon, I've been struggling to encapsulate all related functions in a class as recommended by most people ([How to share values between functions in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729156/how-to-share-values-between-functions-in-python))
This global variable solution in this case seems best as it involves least changes in code